# qtp become "not responding"

Tags: qtp

I am trying to use the childObjects method.
In some cases on large pages (with many objects) I see that qtp become "not responding" and the function return empty list.

On different computer it's work OK but if I continue to increase number of objects in page it also fail.

I try also on facebook (after login) and on www.ynet.co.il and in both cases it failed on one computer and in another it works ok (same qtp11 version).

What can cause this problem ? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In QTP there's a timeout when the browser takes too long to respond, if the timeout occurs during a `ChildObjects` an empty list will be returned. The difference between both your computers is probably that one is faster than the other.

In order to work-around this problem you should try to narrow down the number of elements you're trying to retrieve, add a description while specifying an `html tag` to retrieve only a subset of all the child objects (I don't suppose you really need a list of all the DOM elements). If you *do* actually need all the DOM elements then perhaps you can move the action to the browser-side using the `Browser`'s `RunScript` method (new in QTP11).

If you choose to use the `html tag` in the description it's better if you specify that it's not a regular expression.

```
Set desc = Description.Create()
desc("html tag").Value = "div"
desc("html tag").RegularExpression = False
```

Comment: adding description doesn't help. How can I increase the timeout

Comment: @user1291465 I don't think you can change the timeout, please see my edit to the answer that you should turn off the regular-expressionness of the `html tag`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to set the timeout using

```
Dim SaveDefaultTimeOut: SaveDefaultTimeOut=Setting ("DefaultTimeout")
Setting ("DefaultTimeout")=<newval>
Dim SaveWebTimeout: SaveWebTimeout=Setting ("WebTimeout")
Setting ("WebTimeout")=<newval>
```

to set a higher timeout before the childObjects call, and restore the original timeouts using

```
Setting ("DefaultTimeout")=SaveDefaultTimeOut
Setting ("WebTimeout")=SaveWebTimeout
```

You should, however, always standardize the time values among QTP clients to get comparable results. One way to do this is to set them in a library, by inserting the following lines into a library (on global scrope, not in any routine):

```
Setting ("DefaultTimeout")=5000
Setting ("WebTimeout")=5000
```

As soon as the library is being loaded, the timeouts will be set, overriding the values from the config dialogs.